# CSS for shape does not apply on textarea in javafx

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am applying following CSS.

```
.text-area .content {
    -fx-background-color: -lined-back;
    -fx-shape: "M 7 0 L 24 0 L 24 19 L 0 19 L 0 2 L 7 2 Z";
}

.text-area:focused .content {
    -fx-shape: "M 7 0 L 24 0 L 24 19 L 0 19 L 0 2 L 7 2 Z";
}
```

My problem is it's only changes shape of background not whole component.and also start editing at starting point.as per below image.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the HTML these styles apply to? I know nothing about javafx, but you are currently targeting `.content` inside of `.text-area`. You probably just need to target the `.text-area` itself:

```
.text-area,
.text-area .content {
    -fx-background-color: -lined-back;
    -fx-shape: "M 7 0 L 24 0 L 24 19 L 0 19 L 0 2 L 7 2 Z";
}

.text-area:focused,
.text-area:focused .content {
    -fx-shape: "M 7 0 L 24 0 L 24 19 L 0 19 L 0 2 L 7 2 Z";
}
```

You may even be able to *only* target the `.text-area`, since I would imagine its children would be constrained by its shape.

```
.text-area {
    -fx-background-color: -lined-back;
    -fx-shape: "M 7 0 L 24 0 L 24 19 L 0 19 L 0 2 L 7 2 Z";
}

.text-area:focused {
    -fx-shape: "M 7 0 L 24 0 L 24 19 L 0 19 L 0 2 L 7 2 Z";
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. it is apply only to border of textarea but editing is starts from starting.